# Independence of events and intersection

Tags: probability

Suppose an event $A$ is independent of event $B$. Event $A$ is also independent of event $C$. We also know that $B$ and $C$ are dependent.

Is it true that $A$ is independent of $B\cap C$? I think the answer is yes since if the presence of $A$ doesn't affect either $B$ or $C$, it won't affect their intersection as well. But how do we prove it mathematically?

Comment: Suppose $A$ is the event "a fair penny comes up $H$", suppose $B$ is the event "a fair dime comes up $H$", suppose $C$ is the event "the fair penny and the fair dime match."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $A$ is independent of $B$ and $C$ then why is it not necessarally independent of $B\cap C$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046628/if-a-is-independent-of-b-and-c-then-why-is-it-not-necessarally-independent)